# How do I pass data/stream from a thread to an activity in Android in real-time?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, background, real-time

Basically what I have done is taken source code from two different projects and cobbled it together to try to create a new application that plots Bluetooth data in real-time. The intermediate result is apparently more complicated than I am able to comprehend. I have asked questions, gotten feedback, done a lot of reading, but I am still stuck with what I see as the problem: How do I get data from a data acquisition thread into a plotting activity in real-time? This question requires some explanation.

I started with the source code from [Blueterm](http://pymasde.es/blueterm/), a Bluetooth terminal emulation program which supports SPP/RfComm. First step was to build and run Blueterm on my Android phone and get it to connect and communicate with an external Bluetooth data acquisition device. This went well - device data scrolls across the screen nicely.

Next I went to AndroidPlot and got the source code for [OrientationSensorExample](http://androidplot.com/wiki/OrientationSensorExample), and I added that to my project so that I could start this activity from the Options Menu. This went well also. My application starts the Orientation Sensor activity which plots Orientation Sensor data in real-time while continuing to acquire data from the Bluetooth device in the background also in real-time.

What I want to do now is modify my application so that the Orientation Sensor activity plots the Bluetooth data (not the Orientation Sensor data) in real-time. Using logcat I know for a fact that the Orientation Sensor activity is plotting orientation sensor data in real-time and continuing to acquire Bluetooth data in the background in real-time.

This suggests an architecture: While my application is plotting orientation sensor data in real-time there is a background thread that is continuing to acquire Bluetooth data in real-time. Or another way of looking at it: There was a Bluetooth activity that spawned/generated/created/whatever a background thread (or just a thread) that continues to run even after I have started the Orientation Sensor activity (all of this observed through logcat).

So the question remains: How do I pass data from this background thread (that was started by a Bluetooth activity) into the Orientation Sensor activity?

Comment: I have the same issue where I am reading input from a BT device that is spitting out data at very fast rates.  I basically get about 6k of bytes per second.  Updating this into a static array is not feasible.  I wish the BT mechanism provided for another thread to spawn as it does for AudioRecord or Sensor.  Instead I have to use AsyncTask to create a separate thread to process this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make your data as static or you can use Application class of Android framework.
So that your background thread keep updating the static data and you will retrieve that updated data in your Activity.

Comment: I don't understand @Sujit. Can you be more specific, provide an example?

Comment: you don't need to pass the data form your background thread .just make your object as static and the thread will keep updating it and your activity will get the updated data whenever it needs it.

Comment: Thanks @Sujit but people have said there is only one activity running at a time so I cannot do what I want to do. But based on your suggestion I will make my data in the background thread static. Now tell me what activities can read it? How do they read it?

Comment: OK yes @Sujit but I am lost. I need to: (1) make the data static and (2) read it. So (1) make the data static by doing the following:    static byte[] buffer; BlueSentry.buffer = buffer; and then (2) read it how?

Comment: Please understand @Sujit the data is read via onSensorChanged() so how does my static background thread data generate such event? I believe this is the whole point that no one has been able to address.

Comment: you should read the static buffer in your Orientation Sensor activity by your class name. OrientationActivity.buffer.

Comment: Yes @Sujit but how often do I do the read? What triggers the read event like onSensorChanged() did?

Comment: Thank you @Sujit. It is working. Now please tell me how to vote up your answer - I see people have done it but I don't know how. I could also use a few points to get back up to 15 if you think my question was good.

Comment: @Sujit sorry it requires 15 reputation.