# How pass data between two activities while background activity always running

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, handler, background-process

So as illustration below. i want my background activity (stream data from bluetooth) places in class A always running whenever i change my screen to class B. The UI only update where the screen active, but using the same background activity that always running.

[image: Illustration]

I'm aware that there's only one active activity allowed to run on Android. That's way i try to pass the data using shared preferences from textview UI update on class A, and try to get it in class B. But, when i change the screen to class B, the background activity stop working. So, my shared preferences that i set up earlier only passed the last data.

here's the code :
Obtain data, class A

```
h = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive massage
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                    sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // if end-of-line,
                        String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                        txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + sbprint);            // update TextView

                        SharedPreferences logPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = logPreferences.edit();
                        String textLog = txtArduino.getText().toString();
                        editor.putString("log", textLog);
                        editor.commit();

                    }
                    //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                    break;
                }
            };
        };
```

receive data class B

```
package com.oding.skripsibluetooth3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Datalog extends Activity{

    TextView tvDatalog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_datalog);

        tvDatalog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDatalog);

        SharedPreferences logPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String text = logPreferences.getString("log", "null");
        tvDatalog.setText(text+"\r\n");
    }



}
```

I appreciate any ideas, 
i found that there's someone already encounter the [similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6148112/1446163). And i tried to put static on variable sbprint just like the solution stated, and there's red warning say "Illegal modifier for the variable sbprint; only final is permitted" 
which one is simpler way for specific problem i have?shared-preferences?static variable?or what? and how do i resolve this?
thank you

Comment: you have already asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463590/how-to-pass-the-data-from-background-process-to-another-activity

Comment: take a look to last comment, this is a difference problem than before

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `Service` as background worker. Than you can bind to this service in your `B` `Activity` and get calculated values. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html).

Comment: a `service` is somehow like an `AsyncTask` ?

Comment: async task is a background Thread, usually oneshot execution. Service is also background Thread, usually long running process.